# openFrameworks (C++): Blur, Glow and other classic effects

Tags: c++, drawing, effects, blur, openframeworks

I was doing some simple openframeworks (C++ based) tests drawing different shapes and I was wondering how to apply filters like blur, glow...

I come from an AS3 background where this is a piece of cake. I know it won't be that easy but I'd like to find some kind of lead.

I've read some people is using ofxShader but I can't find any sort of tutorial about it either.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ofXShader can be used for these kinds of effects. As with many OF-addons the code is the docs. So you'll have to dig into the actual ofXShader.h and cpp. Prior knowledge of shaders is presumed and the header-file suggests this: http://www.evl.uic.edu/aej/594/

There are also effects, such as blur, in ofxOpenCV but these can only be applied to images, which would mean that you need to call ofImage.grabScreen, then do the effect and call draw. Shaders are waaay faster.